# Android Navigation - Navigate from dynamically added fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation, android-navigation-graph

So I want to create a navigation flow as depicted in the image below:
[image]

The app is a single activity app. In the MainActivity, I have a FragmentContainerView, which is set to default nav host. Opening the app would show Fragment 1, as it's the starting destination. From the Fragment 1, I'd like to be able to navigate to Fragment 2. In Fragment 2, there is another FragmentContainerView (inner navhost), to which I dynamically add a fragment (Fragment 2a) using fragment transactions. This FragmentContainerView has defaultNavHost set to false.

Now, in the Fragment 2a, there is a button that should navigate the user to Fragment 2b, which should be full screen. I haven't been able to achieve this to work properly though and ran out of ideas.

I've been trying to access the navcontroller of the nested nav host from the Fragment2a like this

```
        Navigation.findNavController(requireActivity(), NESTED NAV HOST ID).navigate(
        Fragment2ADirections.actionFragment2AtoFragment2B()
    )
```

but the Fragment2B didnt show as a "standalone" fragment, it shown on top of Fragment2a. I also tried to access inner nav host's nav controller like this (in Fragment 2a)

```
val navHostFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.pager_container) as NavHostFragment
val nestedNavController = navHostFragment.navController()
```

But all I got was the `null cannot be cast to non-null type androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment` error.

If there's anyone who could help, I'd highly appreciate this. Thanks!